# PHP & Javascript event handling

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, ajax

I know that php is a server-side language.  However I am confused on how to hook up a html button event to a page that uses php.  I understand this will probably involve Javascript, some css and html and maybe Ajax.  I've been looking at some examples but they don't explain the important pieces I am looking for.  In summary I want to see the code for the click event and how php gets notified there was a click.

I apologize if this is a strange question.  I'm used to old application programming and I'm trying to understand some of these newer practices.

Comment: Have you checked out JavaScript's `submit()` method? A common way to notify PHP is by sending form-data (usually handled directly with `<form>` tags, but can be handled using JavaScript).

Comment: there are lots of tutorials for this...do some more research focusing on `ajax`

Comment: Google "PHP form examples" and "PHP $_GET $_POST"

Comment: php builds the page sent to the client, the structure of the page is html, the styling is css and javascript makes it alive. javascript always runs on the client, php on the server. php can't be notified of a click but you could `$_POST` to the server using js or with the client (which would reload the page)

Comment: This is great.  Thanks guys.  I have/had the old event handling model so ingrained in my head I think I was missing some simple key concepts.  It really helps to be able to ask specific questions because sometimes even when you are pouring through tutorials you begin to realize there is a disconnect between what you understand and what you are reading.  I really appreciate the comments and examples.  I feel the lights coming on.

Answer (score 1):

The actual click event will never be sent to PHP. The outcome of the click is what the server (PHP) will see.

For example, if your button redirects the user to a different page, your PHP will be "notified" as soon as the `GET` request reaches your sever.

For a form element, the `submit` button will issue a `POST` request to a certain URL, that request is what you can "interpret" as the click event. The same goes for an AJAX request.

Answer (score 0):

This is a button in your form

```
<form id="form1">
    <div class="col-md-8">
                          <button type="submit" class="submitbtn" id="submitbtn">Save</button>
                        </div>
</form>
```

This is your java-script, usually jquery or even angularjs is awesome to do this trick

```
$("#form1").submit(function () { 


$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                cache: false,
                data:  $("#form1").serializeArray(),
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data.ok) {
                       alert('Awesomeness');
                    }
                    else {
                        alert('Crapness');
                    }

                },
                error: function () {
                    console.log("html error");
                     alert('Crapness');
                }
            });
```

})

Then back in your php you just recieve the data like old school programming, with a post variable

```
$something = $_POST['Forminput'];
if(!empty($something)){

   //do something and return result
   echo "{\"ok\":\"true\", \"data\":\"some data for u\"}";
}
```